# Accessing component properties in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue and I have this simple component:

```
Vue.component('movie-tile', {
  props: ['movie'],
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0, 
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{movie.Id}}</div>'
})
```

It works and the id is properly displayed but I get a warning:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: movie is undefined"

Now: when I change the template like this:

```
  template: '<div>{{movie}}</div>'
```

it works without a problem.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show us where you use the component? i.e. `<movie-tile :movie="..."></movie-tile>`?

Comment: I bind to app.data object, like: <movie-tile v-bind:movie='testMovie'></movie-tile>

Comment: And the strange thing is that it works, but returns a warning

Comment: testMovie: {Id: '1', Name: 'Some Title'}

Comment: Is, perhaps, `testMovie` not initially defined when the parent component is loaded? For example, if it's pulled from an AJAX call or something?

Answer (score 2):

`movie` here is a property of your component you should try something like this :

```
<movie-tile movie="{id : 10 , title : 'Harry Poter'}"></movie-tile>
```

Comment: I do a binding like <movie-tile v-bind:movie='movieData[1]'></movie-tile>. But even if I mock it as suggested, it does not work